# IIS error 404 502 0 XY - random 404 with cache

Tags: iis, http-status-code-404

Our IIS server on Win server 2012 started to return random errors like this:

```
2016-09-06 10:24:03 192.168.169.253 GET /3dModels/Webgl/bfd414ba72b84478/thumbnail.png - 80 - 256.256.256.256 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/53.0.2785.89+Safari/537.36 http://server.example.com/WebModels 404 502 0 46
2016-09-06 10:24:03 192.168.169.253 GET /3dModels/Webgl/b05e8a3f5b634244/thumbnail.png - 80 - 256.256.256.256 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/53.0.2785.89+Safari/537.36 http://server.example.com/WebModels 404 502 0 62
2016-09-06 10:24:03 192.168.169.253 GET /3dModels/Webgl/adb7ebeeb4554dd8/thumbnail.png - 80 - 256.256.256.256 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/53.0.2785.89+Safari/537.36 http://server.example.com/WebModels 404 502 0 78
2016-09-06 10:24:03 192.168.169.253 GET /3dModels/Webgl/92fada3f39254a7a/thumbnail.png - 80 - 256.256.256.256 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/53.0.2785.89+Safari/537.36 http://server.example.com/WebModels 404 502 0 78
```

I didn't find any documentation for error `404.502`. In browser it is just common 404 with returned error html page from IIS. Thumbnails are 100% accessible through browser (tried to open it with direct url) and count of 404 are random. Every reload generates few of them on various PNGs. Funny think is when I disable cache in developer tools, all images are loaded correctly.

Do you have any idea what causes this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, It works now, but I don't know why. Here is some talk about it...

http://forums.iis.net/t/1233477.aspx?HTTP+Error+404+502+Not+Found